# how to add datepicker in dynamically created row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am stuck in a query and its not working.
I created some input textboxes in table row and one button to add new row with same input textboxes when we click on the `add Row` button.

Here is the code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="assigned_date[]" value="" id="assigned_date" class="assigned_date" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('assigned_date[]');?></span>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="last_date[]" value="" id="last_date" class="last_date" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('last_date[]');?></span>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="priority[]" value="" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('priority[]');?></span>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="frequency[]" value="" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('frequency[]');?></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" id="add_button" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Here is the JQuery code to add new row when we click on the add button

```
 function addRow(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

      var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;

        }
      }
    }
```

I am using `jQuery-ui datepicker` to select date from textbox.
Here is `datepicker` code

```
$('.assigned_date').each(function(){
    $('.assigned_date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
});
```

When I click the first textbox which is not created by dynamically then it show the calendar and select the date.
But The Problem is when I click on the add button and it create same row and then if I select the textbox then it not show any calendar. how I can solve this problem..Please help to find the solution.
When I see by inspect element then it show the class name with `hasDatepicker`

Here is created [fiddle][1] please see

https://jsfiddle.net/r83vmv1q/3/

Comment: Hey is there any on available

Comment: is it possible to create a jsfiddle with your code. so we can test it easily.

Comment: @Aneesh Sivaraman ..I update my question with fiddle.. you can see by clicke the following link    https://jsfiddle.net/r83vmv1q/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@M.Tanzil : There is a bug in your code.

1) First select a date in first date picker.

2) Then add a new row.

3) Then select a date in second row.

Second selected date will added to the first row.

I have fixed this issue. The issue is coming because of all the datepickers have same id. I have assign dynamic id's for datepickers.

Please check this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/r83vmv1q/11/).

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of mistakes in your `javascript` code in the fiddle you provided. Also you have to `initialize` the `datepicker` after the functions which creates the inputs you want to bind `datepicker` with.

> Also when you add a row, destroy all the datepicker instances and then
>   rebind the `datepicker` after you append a new row.

Please see the **[modified Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r83vmv1q/4/)** its working.

**NOTE:** All the newly created `rows` and the inputs inside will display the `datepicker` but when you select date in any of the `row` the `selected date` will be displayed in the `top most row` (if inputs having the same classes) so you have to manage that as well. Try using different classes or with unique IDs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats my problem .When I click on add button and it create dynamic row so I also want datepicker selection in Dynamic row

Comment: Ok that issue also been solved. you can check now :)

Comment: Please can you explain me where you change the code and where is the problem so I can understand properly

Comment: You will see in `AddRow` function at the top i added two lines to destroy the instances of `datepicker`, and at the end of `AddRow` function i `reinitialize the datepicker`. so that the newly created rows can also be initialized with it, and thats it.

Comment: its not working .when we click second row and select then it changes only in first row not showing in second row..please check the fiddle

Comment: For that i have given a `NOTE` in my answer.

Comment: @xr33dx : I have updated the answer of M.Tanzil. Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

remove ids  assigned_date and last_date as you creating rows from javascript, it's basic rule id's shouldn't get repeated in html.

use below code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="assigned_date[]" value=""  class="assigned_date datetimepick" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('assigned_date[]');?></span>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="last_date[]" value=""  class="last_date datetimepick" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('last_date[]');?></span>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="priority[]" value="" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('priority[]');?></span>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="frequency[]" value="" />
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('frequency[]');?></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" id="add_button" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

and if you using datetimepicker initialization use below class as identifier

```
$('.datetimepick').datetimepicker({
    format:"Y-m-d H:i",
    timepickerScrollbar:false,
    minDate: 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should verify your js code and why you don't try to use the input type date :

```
[<input type="date">][1]
```

Comment: i prefred datepicker .. date function its not look good in text box

Answer (score 0):

as an advice :
be sure that you to select a date from textbox after the creation of the new element.!